# Regarding checking for file or directory

Tags: c, posix

I have a very simple program here, but it seems to be returning
a "true" value to the query S_ISDIR() even when the directory
entry is not a directory. Can any one pleeas help me. I am using QNX Neurtion RTOS

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat eStat;
    char *root;
    int i;

    root = argv[1];

    while((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        lstat(entry->d_name, &eStat);
        if(S_ISDIR(eStat.st_mode))
            printf("found directory %s\n", entry->d_name);
        else
            printf("not a dir\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

sample output:

```
found directory .
found directory ..
found directory NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO-html.tar.gz
found directory ncurses_programs
found directory ncurses.html
```

Following information may be helpful.
lstat for file is failing with errno set to 2. I am not sure why, can any one know this.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess; since you're not checking for an error after your lstat call, the eStat buffer could be containing the result of the last successful call. Try checking if lstat returns -1.

readdir() on Linux is fundamentally different, so I can't fully test on my system. See the sample programs at [link text](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/l/lstat.html) and [link text](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/r/readdir.html). Modifying the lstat sample code, this seems to work for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
  {
    int ecode = 0;
    int n;
    struct stat sbuf;

    for( n = 1; n < argc; ++n ) {
      if( lstat( argv[n], &sbuf ) == -1 ) {
        perror( argv[n] );
        ecode++;

      } else if( S_ISDIR( sbuf.st_mode ) ) {
        printf( "%s is a dir\n", argv[n] );

      } else {
        printf( "%s is not a dir\n", argv[n] );
      }
    }
}
```

I don't know if that helps any. Note that the readdir() sample code uses opendir() as schot suggested. But I can't explain why your readdir() seems to work regardless.

Comment: yes, you are right lstat returning failure for file, I am not sure why it is returning failure, can u pls help me

Comment: if (lstat(entry->d_name, &eStat) == -1) perror(entry->d_name);

Answer (score 1):

My compiler says: *"warning: 'dir' is used uninitialized in this function"* You may want to add `dir = opendir(root);` after you initialize `root`. And don't forget to add some error checking.

I doubt this causes your problem, [jcomeau_ictx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068136/regarding-checking-for-file-or-directory/4068204#4068204) is probably right. If `lstat` returns -1 it sets `errno` to a value that signifies the type of error. Look at its man page and the man page for `strerror`

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question was asked long time ago, and I found it because [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394584/c-sys-stat-h-functions-s-islnk-s-isdir-and-s-isreg-behaving-oddly). but the answers here didn't really solve the problem, so I decided to post the answer which I wrote on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394584/c-sys-stat-h-functions-s-islnk-s-isdir-and-s-isreg-behaving-oddly/22395261#22395261), such that if anyone had the same problem and used google to find this page, there is a clear answer.

**The real reason of `S_ISDIR` not working as expected is `dp->d_name` contains only the name of the file, you need to pass the full path of the file to `lstat()`.**