# how can I know if I'm pointing on file or directory in c

Tags: c, directory

we been asked to write a c program that copy all content from dir to another even if it have a nested directories.... that is ok with me to copy files from directory to another but the problem is how can I know that I'm pointing now on the other directory and I should access it and bring files inside it ...?

I used mainly opendir, closedir and read dir

Comment: have you looked up the manpages of the functions you need to use? and could you please provide a short example of what you have tried?

Comment: First post the function you use to copy all files in a directory. Then you'll see (or someone will highlight you that) you simply have to add a second loop inside the function to recursively call it for each sub-folder. (by the way, the homework tag is deprecated)

Comment: What OS is this? I'm assuming Linux? Please add a tag for the OS used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regarding checking for file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068136/regarding-checking-for-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

As a first approach, check if your environment supports the `d_type` field in the `dirent` structure. If that fails, you need to call `stat()` for each file.

Comment: +1 I was unaware of the `d_type` field (even though it is not always available).

Comment: ya actually it support d_type.... and my friends told me that I should use it but sorry ...I don't know the syntax "how to use it"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to determine the type of the file system object. Notice that `stat()` accepts the path to the file so you need to construct the path of the file system object being queried as opposed to just using the `d_name` member of the `struct dirent*` returned by `readdir()`.