# C: <sys/stat.h> functions S_ISLNK, S_ISDIR and S_ISREG behaving oddly?

Tags: c, file-type, ls

The code this is taken from compiles fine. It prints file names in a directory with the option of a letter in front of it: either a `d`,`f`,`l`, or `o` depending on their file type (`o` for other). However, I tested it on the directory `/etc/network` which has a symbolic file called `run` and it appeared as `d`? I've tried re-arranging the order of the `if-statements` too, but that gives an unsatisfactory output too. Am I using it incorrectly?

```
while ((ent = readdir (dp)) != NULL) {
    lstat(ent->d_name, &st);
    if (col){
            if(S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)){
                    printf("d\t");
                    }
           else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)){
                    printf("f\t");
                    }
            else if (S_ISLNK(st.st_mode)){
                    printf("l\t");
            }
            else {   
                     printf("o\t");   
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work as an alternative solution:

```
if(col){

            if(ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
                printf("d ");
            else if(ent->d_type == DT_LNK)
                printf("l ");
            else if(ent->d_type == DT_REG)
                printf("f ");
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

In this line: `lstat(ent->d_name, &st);`, `dp->d_name` contains only the name of the file, you need to pass the full path of the file to `lstat()` like this:

```
    char full_path[512] = "DIR_PATH"; //make sure there is enough space to hold the path.
    strcat(full_path, ent->d_name);
    int col = lstat(full_path, &st);
```

BTW, `S_ISDIR`, `S_ISLNK` etc are POSIX macros, not functions.